# Runnable Jar File export warning

Tags: java

When exporting as runnable jar file that time getting following error

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
Exported with compile warnings: CanvasAPI/src/CanvasAPI.java
```

Comment: Warnings are fine. They are warning you so that you can avoid any pit-falls well before

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: There is no any problem.I just want to know when this kind of error occurs.

Comment: They are not errors, they are warnings. They occur when you have some compile warnings.

Answer (score 0):

That was a perfectly valid question!

In Eclipse you can go to Window > Show View > Problems to see the errors/warnings/others displayed in the Problems Window. The description may help to further understand the source of the issue.